# Can I check and change the settings in BIOS under Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bios

When I fully start 14.04, is it possible to check the settings in BIOS without restarting the computer? Furthermore can I change the settings in BIOS? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. BIOS (Basic Input Output System) is only active while the computer boots up. After that the Operating System takes over. BIOS is on a seperate chip and you cannot change it from within the OS.

Comment: can I at least check the settings in BIOS?

Comment: You can do it during the boot phase. Usually you have to press the DEL key or F2. You can lookup which key it is for your system.

Comment: can I check the settings in BIOS without rebooting?

Comment: You can only do that during the boot phase (see my comment above).

Comment: What do you want to see ? You can use dmidecode - see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/querying-dumping-bios-from-linux-command-prompt.html

Comment: That dmidecode trick is a scripting solution, I believe that was not the intent of the asker. Nevertheless good addition to the context of the question. So that's a +1 for you.

Comment: @bod: I want to check if my cpu (intel core dual) has VT-x enabled. virtualization support for allowing virtual machine to support 64 bit os. (I also hope I can change the settings in BIOS, although I don't expect that change take effect until the next reboot, because I need to search internet for finding the virtualization option in BIOS)

Comment: You check for KVM with `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Comment: You can write your own bios, but, take care - see https://www.bios-mods.com/ Your BIOS is a binary file so you can re-write it (I did to enable KVM on this laptop), but, again, take care. A detailed how-to is well beyond what I can write on askubuntu.

Comment: it returns 2. But I still need to check if it is enabled in BIOS. I am using VirtualBox not KVM. Once I get into BIOS after reboot, it can be difficult to find the option for enabling VT-x.

Comment: I use KVM (virt-manager) + spice as it does not require 3rd party apps and performance is quite good. Generally with VBox you can not run 64 bit guests if VT-x is disabled.